# Access 2007 - Auto Refresh Without VBA?

Tags: automation, microsoft-access, refresh, microsoft-access-2007

I have developed a system using Access 2007 and would like to know if it is possible to auto refresh the data within each element of the entire form after the selection changes.

For example: I enter a date, I click "Next Record".  The date remains the same for the now-current record.  However, if I press my "Refresh" button - which I especially added for this very purpose - the correct changes take place.

I would like to know if this process can be automated without the use of VBA?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code after changing the object:

```
SendKeys "{f9}"
```

This will store the buffer into the field(s) elements. It's the same function as menu item `Refresh`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; where shall I add this in, exactly?  I tried via the `Build Event...` function but this option is not there.